# Several cursors in onCreateLoader() method

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I have problems using `CursorLoader`. I need to retrieve phone and email adress for given name.

I implemented methods of `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>` interface. The problem is that I need to get contact_id from table contacts first, and then based on that contact_id I need to query RawContacts/Data table for email and phone.

I can't find example where you have more than one query in `onCreateLoader()`, usually you have return `new CursorLoader(...)`. I have idea of using `managedQuery(..)` method to get id of contact and pass it to `CursorLoader` but I guess this isn't good idea. Any suggestion?

Comment: The question of this thread is your answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957418/loadermanager-with-multiple-loaders-how-to-get-the-right-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OnCreateLoader, there is an id parameter which you can use to change the CursorLoader.

You can do something like

```
onCreateLoader(int id, bundle args) {

    switch(id) {

        case FETCH_CONTACT_ID: {
             //Return CursorLoader for fetching contactID
             break;
        }

        case FETCH_CONTACT_INFO: {
             //Return CursorLoader for fetching raw contacts
             break;
        }
   }
}

OnLoadFinished(Loader loader, Cursor c) {

    switch(loader.getId()) {

     case FETCH_CONTACT_ID: {
         //Contact IDs have been fetched, so start fetching raw contact data
         //Enter the IDs you want to fetch data for in the bundle which will be passed to onCreateLoader()
         mLoaderManager().restartLoader(FETCH_CONTACT_INFO, args);
         break;
    }

    case FETCH_CONTACT_INFO: {
         //Raw contact info has been fetched, do whatever you want with it
         break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i understood you correctly, i will try to implement this. Thank you for helping me understand Loaders.

Comment: No problem.. If you have any trouble implementing this, just comment on this question with your code.. :-)

Comment: But onCreateLoader() has to have a return type.  What is your return type here?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky CursorLoader - https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html